# Why is automatic weights missing from ctrl+p?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I tried it on a fresh project and there I was able to successfully apply automatic weights. Here if I try to do it with empty weights I can't select bones in weight paint mode, so that's not an option. I tried searching for answer but couldn't find any. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: To select bones in weight paint mode see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127805/i-cant-keep-my-armature-in-pose-mode-when-selecting-another-object

Comment: I tried it but I can't select them anyway, however, on a fresh project I'm able to select bones in weight paint mode just fine.

Comment: Still having this problem and cant find a solution anywhere :(

Comment: Grab object first ,then <kbd>&#8679; Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> add rig. There's no *Automatic Weight* that when you just only grab rig

Answer (score 2):

If it help anyone: I had the same issue but was unable to solve this issue. There was no "automatic weights" in ctrl+p menu nor was I able to assign weights in any other way. After an hour of pain, the issue was that my mesh was disabled for selection. So dont forget to uncheck this option :)

Comment: Nice answer. Could be improved to show a screenshot with annotations.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that when I select Armature it highlights all my bones and when I press ctrl + p it seems that the automatic weights is missing as well.

If you're in Object Mode and you hit "a" to select everything, and then hit ctrl + p it shows the automatic weights in the context menu. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too. When I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+mouse click (object data or vertex group) the automatic weight is missing, so the solution is to click on the rig then click the first object, then click the bottom object while holding shift and then when you click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> it shows up. I hope that helps.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you try to apply automatic weights to a curve or something like that be sure that you converted that to MESH with right click when object selected and convert to mesh option.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if your mesh is actually a mesh. I had this problem earlier when I tried to add an amature to a model. The problem was the model was made from curves, when I tried to set the parent with automatic weights the option was missing. When I converted the model  to a mesh and did the same process, the option came up. Hope this helps lol

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when I had not renamed my mesh the option did not appear, soon as I renamed it and selected it along with my armature, the option for *Automatic weights* showed up. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that we have to select mesh before armature.