# Can't Select Bones in Pose Mode (Blender 2.8)

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, transforms

[image]

I parented a mesh to an armature with no topology issues or anything. My mesh has been parented with automatic weights, and it's ready to be animated.

[image]

However, for some reason I cannot select the armature.

[image]

I decided to select it manually from the outliner. I switched from *object mode* to *pose mode*. But then when I try to select a bone, the armature suddenly switches to a weird version object mode, which seems to be synched with the object mode of the mesh - even though it looks like only the armature is selected.

[image]

Currently, the only way for me to select bones to pose them is by manually selecting them in pose mode from the outliner armature tree, which I feel is gonna get old really quickly. Has anyone else found a solution to this issue? Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This is possibly related to the "lock object modes" setting, have a look at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127805/i-cant-keep-my-armature-in-pose-mode-when-selecting-another-object and see if playing with that setting helps.

Comment: @ Sazerac - Wow. That solved everything. Thank you!