# cannot figure out Weight Paint usage

Tags: weight-painting

I have simple rigged mesh by automatic weight, I can see the weight color, but cannot paint in Weight Paint mode.
I switch from Object to Weight Paint mode, and the brush circle do not effect the mesh when LMB pressed.
When I hold ctrl+LMB over mesh it samples the weight into my brush weight.
I can use only the Gradient tool for painting.
It seems that I'm missing something basic here, but i spent entire day looking for answers and tutorials and can't get it work.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: but one can't select the mesh in pose mode.

Comment: sorry, edit: you need to switch your armature to Pose mode, then shift select your mesh and switch it to Weight Paint mode, then select a bone

Comment: thanks but sorry I'm in pose mode hold shift and the mesh cannot be selected.
i use blender 2.8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't keep my armature in pose mode when selecting another object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127805/i-cant-keep-my-armature-in-pose-mode-when-selecting-another-object)

Comment: Oh yes it might be for the reason given by Sazerac, also use the latest version of 2.8 because I wonder if it worked this way several weeks back

Comment: @Sazerac - thanks now i can select the mesh and toggle to Weight Paint, but still can't paint !
I did the same process in 2.79 and I can weight paint just fine. I still do not know how to do it in 2.8 :(

Comment: whan I hold Ctrl+LMB over the mesh I sample the mesh weight into my brush weight (but not subtract weight) does anyone familiar with this phenomen ?

Comment: Check that the vertex groups aren't locked

Comment: vertex groups aren't locked