# Left click selects everything on my minecraft rig (blender 2.8)

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

So im a newer blender user, and recently I've upgraded to 2.8. I redownloaded the 2.8 version of my rig, but when i try to move (lets say the eyes) it selects everything and moves those with it, any fixes? Im using the Boxcape Studios Character Rig V3.

Comment: You need to put the armature in pose mode. Also, 2.8 has changed some behaviour around selection and modes which may be relevant to you, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127805/i-cant-keep-my-armature-in-pose-mode-when-selecting-another-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're in pose mode rather than object mode. It can be found at the top left in your screenshot ( in the dropdown menu that says "object mode").
Pose mode allows you to move bones. In object mode, the entire armature is considered one object.